# com.chaquo.python.PyException: ImportError: Failed to initialize: Bad git executable

Tags: python, android

I am using chaquopy Library read python code using android

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("/Users/cdp/Desktop/YoloV8_model.pt")
def detectOCR(imagePath):
    try:
        results = model(imagePath)
        df = pd.DataFrame(results[0].boxes.data)
        df.sort_values(by=[0], inplace=True)
        df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

        output = ""
        kwh = False
        names = results[0].names

        for i in range(len(df)):
            if names[int(df[5][i])] == "kwh":
                kwh = True
                continue
            output += names[int(df[5][i])]
        if kwh:
            output += " kwh"
        return json.dumps({"status": "success", "msg": "successfully processed", "result": output})
    except:
        return "error"
```

This is python code i am trying to read using android to read this code we need below library so i installed from build.gradle using below code

```
 python {
            version '3.8'
            pip {
          
                install "pandas"
         
                install "ultralytics==8.0.16"
                install "seaborn==0.12.2"
                install "numpy"
                install "opencv-python"
                install "gitpython"
            }
        }
```

It installs successfully so i am able to build code.
but when i run code and try to read code then i am getting below error

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: ImportError: Failed to initialize: Bad git executable.
The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:
    - be included in your $PATH
    - be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
    - explicitly set via git.refresh()

All git commands will error until this is rectified.

This initial message can be silenced or aggravated in the future by setting the
$GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH environment variable. Use one of the following values:
    - quiet|q|silence|s|silent|none|n|0: for no message or exception
    - warn|w|warning|log|l|1: for a warning message (logged at level CRITICAL, displayed by default)
    - error|e|exception|raise|r|2: for a raised exception

Example:
    export GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH=quiet

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/git
export PATH

GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/git
export GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE

GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/git
```

I have checked in machine it already has git located in "/usr/local/bin/git"
but i don't know why this error coming.